# Copying 10 rows of one column to another table based on the Top 10 from a different column

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

Im having a issue with a seemingly simple piece of code. I have a table called Songs_DB which contains details of some songs, including a column called ELO Which is basically a rank for them. I'm Wanting to transfer the values from a column called SONG_ID to a different table called Smartlist based on the songs with the top 10 ELO scores.

The current code i have come up with is as follows-

```
Dim Insert As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SMARTLIST (Song_ID) VALUES (SONG_ID) FROM SONGS_DB WHERE ELO IN (SELECT TOP 10 ELO FROM SONGS_DB ORDER BY ELO [ASC])", con)
    Insert.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This returns the following error-

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.'

IV tried to do this in a few other ways but keep having no luck! What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How do you plan to handle ties, e.g. what if there are 7 songs that tie for the highest `ELO` and then 6 songs tie for the second highest value? Take all 13? Take the first 7 and then the first 3 of the next tie ordered by the artist's [Bacon Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Degrees_of_Kevin_Bacon#Bacon_numbers)? What if that creates another tie?

Answer (score 3):

Use this query:

```
INSERT INTO SMARTLIST (Song_ID) SELECT TOP 10 Song_ID FROM SONGS_DB ORDER BY ELO DESC
```

This will insert only the column Song_ID. 
If you want more columns you must include them like this:

```
INSERT INTO SMARTLIST (Song_ID, Column2) 
SELECT TOP 10 Song_ID, Column2 FROM SONGS_DB ORDER BY ELO DESC
```

I guess you want the rows ordered `DESC` from the higher `ELO` to the smaller. 
If this is not the case just remove `DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use previous answer or correct your own code like that :

```
Dim Insert As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SMARTLIST (Song_ID) select SONG_ID FROM SONGS_DB WHERE ELO IN (SELECT TOP 10 ELO FROM SONGS_DB ORDER BY ELO [ASC])", con)
Insert.ExecuteNonQuery()
```